# Cross-distro way to determine where Nginx config is at

Tags: linux, freebsd, nginx, software-distribution

I'm developing a project that ideally should work on any Linux distribution or FreeBSD with minimal manual effort to install, without having to be packaged in each distribution's repository. It includes an Nginx config file that's copied to `/etc/nginx/` with an install script.

The obstacle: not all OSes store it in the same place. In every Linux I know, it goes in `/etc/nginx/`, but on FreeBSD, it goes in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/`. (My project has Nginx as a dependency, and Nginx *is* expected to be installed through the OS package manager.)

So, what is the best way to programmatically determine where the config file needs to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to make judgments based on different operating systems.

```bsh
if [ -d /etc/nginx ]; then 
    cp YOURFILE /etc/nginx/
elif [ -d /usr/local/etc/nginx/ ]; then
    cp YOURFILE /usr/local/etc/nginx/
else
    cp YOURFILE /some_other_dir/
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. This is such a simple answer, I don't know how I didn't think of this

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to ask nginx directly.

```
nginx -t
```

tests for the default configuration file and shows its location (and also throws an error with the file path if it is not found).

Example:

```
$ nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] open() "/opt/common/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: configuration file /opt/common/conf/nginx.conf test failed
```

From `nginx -h` you might be tempted to use the -V flag.
`nginx -V` will not work in the configuration file if it is not available.

To use this programmatically, refer to the documentation of the required programming language. You are looking for ways to execute the shell command and store the output.

Here one example on how to script it in bash:

```
NGINX_CONFIG_PATH=`nginx -t 2>&1 | grep -m1 -o '/.*.conf'`
cp $INPUT_FILE $NGINX_CONFIG_PATH
```

Breaking it down:

- 2>&1 redirects the nginx STDERR output to STDOUT so we can process it.
- -m1 for grep shows the first occurance only.
- -o narrows down the search to a regex
- /.*.conf search for the first occurance of / up until .conf

Comment: That's not a "programmatic way" as requested though he's unclear about his programmatic way.

Comment: @Rob, this can be made into a programmatic way. As you say, the requestor has not given any information on programming language or requirements.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the suggestion is to parse this command's text output to find the file path? That's so kludgy that I would rather tell my users to do it manually.

Comment: @Yujiri, thank you for your valuable input on this. It would help, if you clarify the programming language. Then the answer can be directed at your specific use case. I have added a kludgy one-liner example for a shell script to my answer. Hopefully it is not too long for your need (which you still haven't elaborated).

Comment: I was not looking for an answer is a specific language, I was looking for a non-kludgy approach. The accepted answer shows what I was looking for: I can test if `/usr/local/etc/nginx` exists to know if it's a platform that puts the Nginx config there.